# How to select all users who are registered in all the same events as current user

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, query-builder

I'm using Symfony 4. I have 3 entities , **User**, **Event**, **EventRegistration**.

```
class User {
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventRegistration", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
public $eventsRegistrations;

}

class Event{
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventRegistration ", mappedBy="event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $registrations;
}

class EventRegistration {
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", inversedBy="registrations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $event;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="eventsRegistrations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;
}
```

I'd like to know how to select all users who are registered in all the same events as current user **using one query** not two as I did.

Right now I have created two queries:

**EventRegistrationRepository**:

```
// select all events ids in where the current user has been registered
public function myEventsIds($user)
{
    $arrayEventssIds = array();
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    foreach ($qb as $registration) {
        array_push($arrayEventssIds , $registration->getEvent()->getId());
    }

    return $registration;
}
```

then in **UserRepository** , select all users having registrations envent ids in arrayEventsIds of current user:

```
public function usersRegistredInTheSameEvents($user, $arrayEventsIds)
{
  //arrayEventsIds contains the events ids selected in the query above

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->innerJoin('u.eventsRegistrations', 'er')
        ->where('er.event IN (:arrayEventsIds)')
        ->andWhere('er.user != :user')
        ->setParameter('arrayEventsIds', $arrayEventsIds)
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->addGroupBy('u.id');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}}
```

How to combine combine these two queries in just one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is DQL version of the query you need (for user repository);

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery(
        "select u from App:EventRegistration er 
         left join App:User u with er.user = u.id
         where er.user != :user_id and 
         er.event in (select identity(er2.event) from App:EventRegistration er2 
         where er2.user = :user_id)")
->setParameter('user_id', $user->getId());

$users = $query->getResult();
```

Hope it's help.

Comment: Hi, can you help me to add in your query, COUNT, how many times each one of the other users registered in the same event of the current user ?

Comment: I mean the number of events in common between the current user and the others.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939883/add-select-count-events-in-common-between-the-current-user-and-the-others-in-dql

Comment: I answered your new post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939883/add-select-count-events-in-common-between-the-current-user-and-the-others-in-dql/63943754#63943754